# Fermenting pickles - sun or shade?

Tags: fermentation, pickling

I am fermenting pickles in a glass jar, using a brine of 1 TBS salt to a glass of water and a bit vinegar. Should I place the jar in a sunny location or in the shade?

Answer (score 4):

In general, cooler temps mean slower fermentation, and, in my opinion, better flavor.  I would go for a cool, dark place.  Beyond that you'll want to make sure that you have the correct percentage of salt to pickle...3.5% by weight at least.  Too low a concentration, and bad bacteria will survive.  There are lots of internet resources, but Sandor Katz is the expert [This is his site](http://www.wildfermentation.com/).

Comment: Things don't stay as crisp in warm/hot water.